# Workaround for applications which use file system dialog that does not enable to open masked folders (beginning with a dot)?

Tags: xfce, dot-files, dialog

I want to migrate from keepass2 to keepassxc. I am under Debian 12 with XFCE. When I want to open my keypass store located at dot-folder `~/.keepass` , the file system dialog of keepassxc does not enable to input a path, it is just clicking on lists and it does not show dot-folders (which names start with a dot). I could see this problem with other apps.

Is it an app problem or a XFCE standard dialog problem or something else?
I could move my keepass store in a non masked folder, but I wonder how I can solve or workaround this problem without moving my files?

Comment: Can you screenshot the dialog? If you right-click the file list, is there a checkbox to show hidden files? Or if there's a textbox to enter the filename, you could enter the folder name there to open it, perhaps?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat no checkbox nor textbox.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please?